# Wordpress get_results from mysql where string not giving results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am writing a small wordpress plugin. I am trying to get results from an sql query using get_results . In the query I have a variable. When this variable has numeric value the query gives results. When I have string that contains characters  the query doesn’t give me results. I have test the query directly to phpmyadmin and it is giving results either  I try with numeric either I am trying with characters 
this is what I am trying :

```
<?php $myprnum =  $_POST['myprnum']; $mytestproducts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_Parts.id, wp_Parts.ProductName,wp_Parts.ProductPrice,wp_Parts.ProductDescription,wp_Parts.partnumber,wp_Categories.CategoryName FROM wp_Parts INNER JOIN wp_Categories ON wp_Parts.CategoryID=wp_Categories.id WHERE wp_Parts.partnumber LIKE $myprnum");?>
```

When myprnum is "1234" the query gives results. when the myprnum is "ABCD" is not giving results. but when i try to phpmyadmin the query

```
SELECT wp_Parts.id, wp_Parts.ProductName,wp_Parts.ProductPrice,wp_Parts.ProductDescription,wp_Parts.partnumber,wp_Categories.CategoryName FROM wp_Parts INNER JOIN wp_Categories ON wp_Parts.CategoryID=wp_Categories.id WHERE wp_Parts.partnumber LIKE 'ABCD'
```

is giving normally results

Comment: Try adding single quotes in your query statement for the variable $myprnum. 

$mytestproducts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_Parts.id, wp_Parts.ProductName,wp_Parts.ProductPrice,wp_Parts.ProductDescription,wp_Parts.partnumber,wp_Categories.CategoryName FROM wp_Parts INNER JOIN wp_Categories ON wp_Parts.CategoryID=wp_Categories.id WHERE wp_Parts.partnumber LIKE '$myprnum'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a single quote around the variable i.e. '$myprnum'. So your query will be something like the below:

```
<?php $myprnum =  $_POST['myprnum']; $mytestproducts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_Parts.id, wp_Parts.ProductName,wp_Parts.ProductPrice,wp_Parts.ProductDescription,wp_Parts.partnumber,wp_Categories.CategoryName FROM wp_Parts INNER JOIN wp_Categories ON wp_Parts.CategoryID=wp_Categories.id WHERE wp_Parts.partnumber LIKE '".$myprnum."' ");?>
```

Comment: Thank you this was the issue

Comment: Glad, it helped you!! :)

Comment: Please if you explain a small  why without single qutoe they are not working@DebakantMohanty

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing with single quotes will work out for you.
    `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_Parts.id, wp_Parts.ProductName,wp_Parts.ProductPrice,wp_Parts.ProductDescription,wp_Parts.partnumber,wp_Categories.CategoryName FROM wp_Parts INNER JOIN wp_Categories ON wp_Parts.CategoryID=wp_Categories.id WHERE wp_Parts.partnumber LIKE '".$myprnum."');?>`